# What will happen if wrong arguement is passed into MPI_Allreduce?

Tags: fortran, mpi

I was writing fortran using MPI_Allreduce. I accidently put MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION instead of MPI_INTEGER to get the integer sum. Sometimes I will get a correct answer sometimes I will get some very huge negative numbers. I was taking the parallel computing course and check my textbook. I did not found that what will exactly happen if I passed the wrong MPI_Datatype to MPI_Allreduce. **Plus, the compiler or the code does not complain at all which making debugging extremely difficult!** Is there a method to identify wrong MPI_Datatype is passed into MPI_Allreduce? Could somebody explain a bit more about how MPI_ALlreduce will work if wrong argument is passed into?

Many thanks!

Comment: (a) Fortran will not baby you in this respect. The responsibility is on you to write the correct code. (b) Why not just fix the problem? What are you hoping to gain by learning how it will work in this failed case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, an incorrect program has an undefined behavior.

In your case, using `MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION` instead of `MPI_INTEGER` will likely result in array overflows, and hence memory corruption, and then all bets are off.

Also, you will be using an operator (`+` is `MPI_SUM`) that operates on floating numbers instead of integers, which is incorrect.
Feel free to learn the format of `DOUBLE PRECISION` numbers and see what happens if you treat them as integers and perform an addition.